# Android Studio cannot find my device ! (Initializing ADB)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, connect, initializing

I'm struggling to connect my device(Galaxy S10) in Android Studio.

I used several methods to solve this problem, but it didn't work.

[Methods that I tried]
 - Delete all android studio files and re-install it.  ( gradle, sdk, etc.... )
 - Add the PATH  ( C\users....\Android\Sdk\platform-tools )
 - Re-install the USB driver.
 - Reset the adb using cmd.  ( adb kill-server , adb start-server )

As you can see in the picture.

The connection assistant in Android Studio can find the Galax S10, but I cannot connect.

Please help me to solve this problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging in Developer options in your Galaxy S10?

Comment: enable developer options and usb dubug mode, then allow to connect to your computer and then you should try to change connection type in notification. Try to select PTP, or file transfer mode or MIDI. Sometimes that can help, You can also try to use in Android studio where devices list, option Troubleshoot device connections

Comment: I already enabled USB debugging in Developer options.

Comment: keep trying different suggestions, reboot pc, for example, reenable debug mode on phone, play with connection types google some other tips.. there is something mysterious in adb connection. from my experience

Comment: type ```adb devices``` in your cmd prompt and see is any error going on first

Comment: I typed adb devices , but it showed nothing.

Comment: Are your computer block usb port? If your port is blocked by some security reason, make sure it's opened when you plug your phone in.

Answer (score 1):

try installing adb driver from samsung's website [Link](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This issue not created by **android studio** or **gradle file**. Actually this issue is caused by **adb drivers**.Let install adb drives manually in your device. then check connect mobile with android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following things to remember for connecting your phone.

1. Always install the driver from a trusted source.
2. Developer mode should be activated and USB debugging mode also enables.
3. Please make sure some devices require to set USB settings to file transfer mode.
4. In some rare cases after connecting the device we have to restart the ADB.

   **Step to restart ADB in Window:**

   Go to the task manager and search for ADB and end that task.

   **Step to restart ADB in Ubuntu:**

   Go to the System Monitor and search for ADB and kill that task.

Now go to Android Studio and try to select devices from the device list panel. And hopefully, you will be able to see your connected device.

**NOTE : Connect the device to USB file transfer before kill the ADB and do not disconnect your device after killing ADB**

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why Android Studio doesn't see mobile phones.

One of them is a problem with the **ADB Interface driver**. You can check it in your Device Manager:

[image: ADB Interface]

To solve this issue, follow these steps :

1. Connect your mobile phone with the PC using the cable and Enabled the **Developer Option** and **USB Debugging**, which you normally do
2. Download this [Android SDK](https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip)
3. Unzip the Zip file and go to the android-sdk-windows folder -> Run **SDK Manager.exe** with admin privileges

[image: Android SDK Manager]

4. Search for **Google USB Driver**, Put a checkmark on it and  click on Install packages... button

( Now the driver is downloaded but it won't install automatically. We will do it manually in the next steps. )

5. Open the Device Manager (Right-click on the Start menu -> Device Manager)
6. In the Device Manager locate your Android device. Then right-click on it and select "Update Driver Software".
7. Select "Browse my computer for driver software".
8. Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer".
9. Select "Show All Devices" and click on the Next button
10. Press the "Have Disk" button.
11. Enter the path to the Google USB driver. ( To know where your Google USB Driver downloaded, just hover your mouse on it you will find the path/location ) [See the below image]

[image: the path]

12. Select "Android ADB Interface" from the list of device types.
13. Confirm the installation of the driver by pressing "Yes".
14. Confirm the installation again by pressing "Install".
15. When the installation is done, press "Close".

Now, your Android device will be picked up by the Android Studio :)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the matter of a wrong USB cable :/